# How to inheritance function from the main object to other objects dynamic?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance

***I want to create dynamic new objects (someAnimal) in this case for example `frog` under object '`Game`'.***

Inside `Game.frog` I want to inheritance from `Game` the function init to `frog`
So also frog will have function `init` 
and all other animals will clone the function `init`.

```
 Game.frog.init(), Game.lion.init() ...... Game.n...int()
```

**the Animal will be like below**

Many Thanks for any help.

```
Game.frog = {
    init: function(){
        this.property1 = something;
        this.property2 = something;
        this.property3 = something;
        this.property1000 = something;
    } 
};
```

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
var Game = {
    init: function(){
        this.property1 = 1;
        this.property2 = 2;
        this.property3 = 3;
        this.property1000 = 1000;
    },

     cons: function(gameAnimals){

        for(var i = 0; i < gameAnimals.length; i++){
             this.gameAnimals[i] = {};
             this.gameAnimals[i].init() = this.init();
            //or         
            //gameAnimals[i].prototype = new Game();        // someAnimal inheritance from Game 
            //gameAnimals[i].prototype.constructor=gameAnimals[i];      // frog constructor
        }
     }    
};

var gameAnimals = ['frog', 'lion', 'cat'];
Game.cons(gameAnimals);
alert(Game.frog[0]+' '+Game.frog[1]+' '+Game.frog[2]+' '+Game.frog[2]);//display  1 2 3 1000
                                                                        //frog.property2 = 2;
                                                                        //frog.property3 = 3;
                                                                        //frog.property1000 = 1000;
}//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: i guess you should write: this.gameAnimals[i].init = this.init; so no () which call the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really reconsider the way you are trying to access your "animals"...
Try this:

```
window.onload = function () {

    function Animal(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.property1 = 1;
      this.property2 = 2;
      this.property3 = 3;
      this.property1000 = 1000;
    }

    function Game() {
      this.animals = {};

      this.addAnimal = function (animalName) {
        this.animals[animalName] = new Animal(animalName);

      };
    }


    var game = new Game();

    game.addAnimal('frog');
    game.addAnimal('lion');
    game.addAnimal('cat');

    alert(game.animals.frog.name +"; " + game.animals.frog.property1 +"; " + game.animals.frog.property2);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not create an Animal function which you can then instantiate for each of your critters:

```
function Animal() {
    self = this;
    self.init = function() {
        self.property1 = 1;
        self.property2 = 2;
        self.property3 = 3;
        self.property1000 = 1000;
    }
}

var frog = new Animal();
frog.init();
```

Also maybe have a read of this : http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html  to get some ideas on JS inheritance patterns.